# How to display formatted numbers from a cell array with n decimal places

Tags: matlab, format, cell-array

I have a cell array that contains both numbers and strings. I want to print the cell array so that I will see only 5 numbers after the decimal point. For example:

```
c{1, 1} = pi;
c{2, 1} = pi / 2;
c{3, 1} = pi / 4;
c{4, 1} = 2 ^ 0.5;
```

After using `format long` this is what I receive:

```
>> c
c = 
    [3.141592653589793]
    [1.570796326794897]
    [0.785398163397448]
    [1.414213562373095]
```

But I want that the output will be:

```
>> c
c = 
    [3.14159]
    [1.57079]
    [0.78539]
    [1.41421]
```

Comment: `format short` displays 4 digits after the decimal place.  Too few?

Comment: for "printing" use `fprintf` or `sprintf` - for "displaying" it's a bit more complicated. Though I suppose you could override `disp` with  your code (containing fprintf I suppose)

Comment: @chappjc the cell array also has strings in it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to generate a formatted string, *e.g*:

```
sprintf('%.5f\n', c{:})
```

For your example, the result would be:

```
ans =
    3.14159
    1.57080
    0.78540
    1.41421
```

Unlike [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html), generating your own string allows you to tweak the number of digits displayed after decimal point to any value you desire.

If your cell array contains non-numerical values (such as strings), you can do the following hack:

```
c_fmt = c;                                              %// Temporary cell array
idx = cellfun(@isnumeric, c(:));                        %// Locate numbers
c_fmt(idx) = cellfun(@(x){sprintf('%.5f', x)}, c(idx)); %// Format as strings
```

which essentially converts the numbers to formatted strings. Displaying the resulting `c_fmt` should give you an acceptable output.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> preferences pick "command window" from the list on the left.
Change the "Text display" from `'long'` to `'short'`

```
c = 
[3.1416]
[1.5708]
[0.7854]
[1.4142]
```

Comment: He asked for five digits, not four.

Comment: The quick way to achieve this would of course be typing `format short`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `compose`:

```
disp(cell2mat(compose('%1.4f',cell2mat(c))))
```

This will give you a char per row. To convert it to an array:

```
str2num(cell2mat(compose('%1.4f',cell2mat(c))))
```