# How to display with n decimal places from cell array that also contain strings in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, format, cell-array

Hello I have a cell array that contains numbers, and also strings. I want to print the cell array so that I will see only 5 number after the decimal point, the strings need to be the same

Example:

```
for i=1:3
    c{1,i*2-1} = pi
    c{2,i*2-1} = pi/2
    c{3,i*2-1} = pi/4
    c{4,i*2-1} = 2^0.5

    c{1,i*2} = 'emperiment_number_7_result_21_total_5_and_ext'
    c{2,i*2} = 'emperiment_number_4_result_21_total_5_and_ext'
    c{3,i*2} = 'emperiment_number_6_result_21_total_5_and_ext'
    c{4,i*2} = 'emperiment_number_12_result_11_total_5_and_ext'
end
```

After writing format long this is what I receive

```
>> c
c = 
    [3.141592653589793]    'emperiment_number_7_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [3.141592653589793]    'emperiment_number_7_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [3.141592653589793]    'emperiment_number_7_result_21_total_5_and_ext' 
    [1.570796326794897]    'emperiment_number_4_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [1.570796326794897]    'emperiment_number_4_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [1.570796326794897]    'emperiment_number_4_result_21_total_5_and_ext' 
    [0.785398163397448]    'emperiment_number_6_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [0.785398163397448]    'emperiment_number_6_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [0.785398163397448]    'emperiment_number_6_result_21_total_5_and_ext' 
    [1.414213562373095]    'emperiment_number_12_result_11_total_5_and_ext'    [1.414213562373095]    'emperiment_number_12_result_11_total_5_and_ext'    [1.414213562373095]    'emperiment_number_12_result_11_total_5_and_ext'
```

If I write format short this is what I get:

```
>> c
c = 
    [3.1416]    [1x45 char]    [3.1416]    [1x45 char]    [3.1416]    [1x45 char]
    [1.5708]    [1x45 char]    [1.5708]    [1x45 char]    [1.5708]    [1x45 char]
    [0.7854]    [1x45 char]    [0.7854]    [1x45 char]    [0.7854]    [1x45 char]
    [1.4142]    [1x46 char]    [1.4142]    [1x46 char]    [1.4142]    [1x46 char]
```

But I want that the output will be: (no [1x46 char] and 5 numbers after the decimal [ also 4 will be good but 5 is better])

```
>> c
c = 
    [3.14159]    'emperiment_number_7_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [3.14159]    'emperiment_number_7_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [3.14159]    'emperiment_number_7_result_21_total_5_and_ext' 
    [1.57079]    'emperiment_number_4_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [1.57079]    'emperiment_number_4_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [1.57079]    'emperiment_number_4_result_21_total_5_and_ext' 
    [0.78539]    'emperiment_number_6_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [0.78539]    'emperiment_number_6_result_21_total_5_and_ext'     [0.78539]    'emperiment_number_6_result_21_total_5_and_ext' 
    [1.41421]    'emperiment_number_12_result_11_total_5_and_ext'    [1.41421]    'emperiment_number_12_result_11_total_5_and_ext'    [1.41421]    'emperiment_number_12_result_11_total_5_and_ext'
```

Thank you

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? It should not be that hard to adapt the answer from your similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370661/how-to-display-with-n-decimal-places-from-cell-array-in-matlab

Comment: why the new question?? just edit the old one!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I wrote what I tried so far.. format long format short I was not able to use the methods in the other question

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus I flogged the old question for delete, Because the answers to that question will not fit into this question. and it will create confusion.

Comment: Actually the answer by @EitanT would make a good base for an answer to this question. However I won't write it out unless you try it yourself first.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Too late, already updated mine =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **fprintf**

```
    for i=1:3
       fprintf('%1.5f %s %3.5f %s %5.5f %6s \n',c{i,:})
    end
```

Comment: great but what if the strings are not in the same sizes? then the data is not stight..

Comment: @user2236185 You want to truncate the strings to a fixed length ?